# Touch area of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a button on a UICollectionViewCell which has a hit area larger than the cell, but I'm unable to achieve this. It seems that touch events for a cell are not intercepted outside of the cell - unfortunately there seem to be no questions on SO which address this, so I'd be really happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Please, no answers which suggest I re-size the cell - this isn't an option in this case.

Comment: Any luck getting this to work?

Comment: Nope - the only thing I thought of which feels really hacky is to get the touch in the containing view, & pass it on to the cell. You have to do stuff to convert the coordinates of course